# What is the smallest number of nowhere dense affine subsets covering a topological group?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-groups, cardinal-characteristics

$\DeclareMathOperator\cov{cov}\newcommand\A{\text A}$A subset $A$ of a group $G$ is called *affine* if $A=xHy$ for some subgroup $H\subseteq G$ and some $x,y\in G$.

Given a non-discrete topological group $G$, let $\cov_\A(G)$ be the smallest cardinality of a cover of $G$ by nowhere dense affine subsets.

**Problem 1.** Is $\cov_\A(G)=\mathfrak c$ for every uncountable Polish (compact abelian) group $G$?

The following special case of Problem 1 is especially interesting for me:

**Problem 2.** Is $\cov_\A(C_2^\omega)=\mathfrak c$ for the compact metrizable Boolean group $C_2^\omega$?

**Problem 3.** Is $\cov_\A(X)=\mathfrak c$ for every separable Banach space $X$ of positive dimension?

**Remark.** It can be shown that $\cov_\A(G)=\mathfrak c$ for every non-discrete abelian Lie group $G$.
Also it is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/q/330311/61536) that a separable Banach space cannot be covered by less than continuum closed hyperplanes. On the other hand, for any uncountable cardinal $\kappa$, the Hilbert space $\ell_2(\kappa)$ of density $\kappa$ can be covered by $\kappa$ many nowhere dense linear subspaces.

---

**Added in Edit.** I have just realized that Problem 2 (and hence Problem 1) has negative answer under the set-theoretic assumption $\mathfrak u<\mathfrak c$. Let us recall that $\mathfrak u$ is the smallest cardinality of a base of a free ultrafilter on $\omega$.

**Theorem.** If a topological group $G$ admits a continuous homomorphism onto the countable power $F^\omega$ of a nontrivial finite group $F$, then $\cov_A(G)\le\mathfrak u$.

*Proof.* Fix a free ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\omega$ that has a base $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal U$ of cardinality $|\mathcal B|=\mathfrak u$. For every $B\in\mathcal B$ consider the closed nowhere dense subgroup $$H_B=\{x\in F^\omega:x[B]=\{1_F\}\}$$ in $F^\omega$. Here $1_F$ is the identity of the group $F$. For every $y\in F$ let $\bar y$ be the constant function $\omega\to\{y\}$. It is easy to see that $$F^\omega=\bigcup_{y\in F}\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal B}\bar yH_B,$$ which implies $$\cov_A(G)\le \cov_A(F^\omega)\le |F|\cdot\mathfrak u=\mathfrak u.$$

---

Therefore, Problem 2 have negative answer and Problem 1 remains open for connected topological groups:

**Problem 1'.** Is $\cov_\A(G)=\mathfrak c$ for every nontrivial connected Polish (compact abelian) group $G$?

Comment: So an affine subset is just a coset of a subgroup?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, exactly. But a "coset of a subgroup" sounds longer that "affine subset".

Comment: Let me say "coset" instead of "affine subset" and $C_2$ cyclic of order 2. A first remark is that in Problem 1, it's enough to consider closed cosets: the question is whether an uncountable Polish group can never be covered by less than continuum many non-open closed cosets. In the compact group $C_2^\omega$, if $a+F$ is a non-open closed coset, then $F\cup (a+F)$ is a non-open closed subgroup. Hence Problem 2 is the same as asking whether $C_2^\omega$ can't be covered by less that continuum many non-open closed subgroups.

Comment: @YCor You are right. For periodic groups "affine" can be replaced by "subgroup" and "nowhere dense" by "closed nonopen". But such changes of termonilogy do not help to answer the questions. And for other groups like the circle group "affine sets" (or "coset") cannot be replaced by "subgroups" since such groups are not covered by nowhere dense subgroups.

Comment: For periodic *abelian* groups. Well, it might help in case the "subgroup" question is more classical and rings bells. Anyway, it was just a remark.

Comment: Is the consistency of ZF known to imply that of (ZFC+ $\mathfrak{u}<\mathfrak{c}$)?

Comment: @YCor Yes, it is known that $\mathfrak u<\mathfrak c$ is consistent, see e.g. Section 7 of the survey http://www.math.cmu.edu/~eschimme/Appalachian/BLASS.pdf

Comment: In the theorem it suffices to require that $\mathcal B$ is a $\pi$-base of a free ultrafilter, so we can replace  $\frak u$ by $\frak r$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, Alex, I also realized this fact and wanted to write you about this discovery. But you was faster.

Comment: @AlexRavsky By the way, for the $p$-solenoids $G$ (i.e. Pontryagin duals of the group $C_{p^\infty}=\{z\in\mathbb C:\exists n\in\mathbb N\;z^{p^n}=1\}$) we have $cov_A(G)=\mathfrak c$ since each nowhere dense subgroup of $G$ is trivial, which follows from the fact that each non-trivial subgroup of $C_{p^\infty}$ is finite. Therefore, for $cov_A(G)$ we have dichotomy. For some topological groups (like $p$-adic solenoids or Lie groups) we have $cov_A(G)=\mathfrak c$ and for some other (for example, compact periodic) we have $cov_A(G)\le\mathfrak r$. Where is the borderline between these cases?

Comment: @TarasBanakh the Pontryagin dual of $C_{p^\infty}$ is the underlying group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ of $p$-adics (you seem to use $\mathbf{Z}_p$ for another meaning). What's called solenoid is rather the Pontryagin dual of the torsion-free group $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$ (or more general subgroups of $\mathbf{Q}$?), which is connected.

Comment: @YCor Of course you are right concerning the terminology:  writing "solenoid" I had in mind the group of $p$-adic integers.