# Topological spaces with nowhere locally constant functions to the reals

Tags: gn.general-topology

I would like a nice characterization of topological spaces with continuous functions to the reals which are nowhere locally constant, i.e. not constant on any (non-empty) open set. For sure, the property I just gave is itself a characterization. I just wouldn't call it nice. Spaces with this property can look very different from one another. For examples, the rationals (and the identity function), the irrationals (and the identity function), $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and projection), Cantor space.

Comment: On any *non-empty* open set, of course.  (I guess one calls the function on the empty set constant.)  Do you know a non-atomic space that does *not* have this property?

Comment: @LSpice how about the long line? (I'm not sure what you mean by atomic, but I don't think the long line is that.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423515/topological-spaces-with-nowhere-locally-constant-functions-to-the-reals#comment1088381_423515), I meant by an atom of a space a minimal non-empty open set.  So, certainly the long line is non-atomic!

Comment: Recall that a point $z_0$ in a space $Z$ is a $P$-point if the intersection of countably many neighborhoods of $z_0$ is still a (not necessarily open) neighborhood of $z_0$. If $X$ is a completely regular space, and the Stone Cech compactification$\beta X$ has a $P$-point $x_0$, then every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is constant in a neighborhood of $x_0$. Is there an example of such a completely regular space $Y$ where $\beta Y$ has no $P$-points?

Comment: Consider the quotient space $Y=((\omega_1+1)\times\{0\})\cup(\omega+1)\times\{1\})/\simeq$ where we set $(\omega_1,0)\simeq(\omega,1)$. Then $Y$ has no $P$-points but every continuous function from $Y$ to $[0,1]$ is constant on some open set.

Comment: Do you think every perfect metric space has your property?  (This would include rational, irrationals, and Cantor space.  Plus a lot more.)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I think so. Pick a point p in the metric space, and let f(x) be the distance from x to p. Haven't checked the details tbh.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky. That does not work for ultrametric spaces like the $p$-adic spaces.

Comment: @LSpice The long line is not a counter-example (i.e. it does have the property in question), basically because the Cartesian product of the reals (or, more generally, any space with this property) with any space at all still has this property.

Comment: @JosephVanName One does not even need an example that exotic to see that my answer was wrong. Consider the subspace of the plane consisting of the origin (which I take to be the point p) and those circles centered at the origin with radius $1/n$. The function I gave is constant on each circle.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423515/topological-spaces-with-nowhere-locally-constant-functions-to-the-reals#comment1088433_423515), the long line was not my example.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky if $L$ is the long line, then every continuous function $f \colon L \to \mathbf R$ is eventually constant.

Comment: Proof: Recall that $L$ has the order topology, and that any countable increasing sequence in $L$ converges. For $n \in \mathbf N$, look at the open $U_n\subseteq L\times L$ given by $\{(x,y) : \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<2^{-n}\}$. It contains the diagonal, hence also $[x_n,\infty)\times[x_n,\infty)$ for some $x_n \in L$ (if not, produce a strictly increasing sequence $y_0<y_1<\ldots$ such that $(y_i,y_{i+1})\in U_n^c$, with limit point $(y,y)\in U_n^c$ as $U_n^c$ is closed). Setting $x=\lim x_n$ gives $[x,\infty)\times[x,\infty)\subseteq \bigcap_n U_n$, i.e. $f$ is constant on $[x,\infty)$.

Comment: It seems that this class contains all separable functionally Hausdorff spaces (but this is a rather trivial observation).

Comment: Since we seem not to be able to find a good answer, can anyone suggest where else I might turn?

Comment: @TarasBanakh That's not quite right. A countable, discrete space is separable and functionally Hausdorff, but every function is everywhere locally constant. We could make the further assumption that all points are closed and not open. Even then I don't see why the assertion is true. I could use a countable dense subset X to build a countable sequence of continuous functions so that the pointwise limit of that sequence is defined and 1-to-1 on X. But I can't guarantee that this pointwise limit is continuous. Uniform continuity doesn't help because that notion does not even apply to all spaces.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Aha, then a good problem would be to prove that a crowded separable functionally Hausdorff space admits a nowhere locally constant function. Right?

Comment: @RobertLubarsky And this can be done as follows: Using the functional Hausdorffness of $X$, find a continuous injective map $g$ of $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space $K$ such that $g[X]$ is dense in $K$. Consider the Banach space $C(K)$ and observe that for distinct points $x,y$ of $K$ the set $\{f\in C(K):f(x)=f(y)\}$ is a closed hyperplane in $C(K)$. Use Baire Theorem to find a function $f\in C(K)$ that avoid countably many such closed hyperplanes and hence is injective on the image $d[D]$ of a countable dense subset $D$ of $X$. Then $f\circ g$ will be a required nowhere constant function.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Using the fact that a separable Banach space  is not the union of $<\mathfrak c$ closed hyperplanes, by the above method one can prove that any crowded space $X$ of density $<\mathfrak c$ that admits an injective continuous map onto a metrizable separable space has a nowhere locally constant continuous real-valued function.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes, your proof for a crowded separable f.H. space is correct. One can also bring it back down to Earth, and avoid the g.a.n. by working directly with a countable dense subset and building the desired function by hand (as I tried to do before but needed a tad more cleverness). I don't follow your last reply though. With such an X, what separable Banach space do you use? Why is your claim about a sep Ban space not being such a union true? How does this generalize the case of X separable, since it's unclear (to me) the we are guaranteed an injective cont. func. on X?

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Indeed, such a function can be constructed "by hand" as a sum of a suitable series.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky My last reply uses the fact that a separable Banach space cannot be represented as the union of $<\mathfrak c$ hyperplanes (see answer of Fedja to this question https://mathoverflow.net/q/330311/61536). For non-separable Banach spaces is it not so as shown by the Hilbert space of density $\aleph_1$. For more information on this topic, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.05097.pdf

Comment: @RobertLubarsky And this separability requirement for a Banach space explains why I assume that a crouwded space $X$ of density $<\mathfrak c$ admits a continuous injective function to a metrizable separable space $Y$. In this case I can take any metrizable compactification $K$ of $Y$, consider the Banach space $C(K)$ and in this Banach space look for a function $f:K\to R$ that separates images in $Y$ of points from the dense set of cardinality $<\mathfrak c$ in $X$.

Comment: @RobertLubarsky By the way, this last remark can be substantially improved: every crowded submetrizable space of density $<\mathfrak c$ has a nowhere locally constant real-valued function. I will write this result as a partial answer because it is not entirely trivial.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Taras, did you get the email I sent you?

Comment: @RobertLubarsky Please send me your email to the address t.o.banakh@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Some partial answers to this problem are given by the following theorems.

**Theorem 1.** *Every submetrizable space $X$ of density $<\mathfrak c$ admits a continuous nowhere locally constant real-valued function.*

*Proof.* Let $D$ be a dense set of cardinality $<\mathfrak c$ in $X$. Being submetrizable, the space $X$ admits a bijective continuous map $\varphi:X\to M$ onto a metrizable space. It follows that $\varphi[D]$ is a dense set in $M$ and hence $M$ has density $<\mathfrak c$. Repeating the trick from the proof of Proposition 1 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.01667.pdf), one can show that the metrizable space $M$ admits a bijective continuous map $\psi:M\to Y$ onto a metrizable separable space $Y$. Then $g=\psi\circ\varphi:X\to Y$ is a bijective continuous map from $X$ onto the metrizable separable space $Y$.

Take any metrizable compactification $K$ of $Y$, and consider the Banach space $C(K)$ of all continuous real-valued functions on $K$. Observe that for any distinct points $a,b\in D$ the set $H_{a,b}=\{f\in C(K):f(g(a))=f(g(b))\}$ is a closed hyperplane in $C(K)$.

The metrizability of $K$ implies that the Banach space $C(K)$ is separable. By an old result of Klee (see Proposition 13 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.05097.pdf)), a separable Banach space cannot be covered by less than continuum closed hyperplanes. In particular, the separable Banach space $C(K)$ cannot be covered by the closed hyperplanes $H_{a,b}$ where $a,b\in D$, $a\ne b$. So, there exists a function $f\in C(K)$ such that $f\circ g(a)\ne f\circ g(b)$ for any distinct points of the set $D$.

The density of the set $D$ in the crowded space $X$  implies that the function $f\circ g:X\to\mathbb R$ is locally nowhere locally constant (being injective on the dense set $D$). $\quad\square$

A subset of a topological space is called *$\sigma$-discrete* if it can be written as the union of countably many closed discrete subsets.

**Theorem 2.** *Every crowded normal space with a dense $\sigma$-discrete subset admits a nowhere locally constant continuous real-valued function.*

*Proof.* Let $D$ be a dense $\sigma$-discrete set in a normal space $X$. Write $D$ as the union $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}D_n$ of pairwise disjoint closed discrete subsets in $X$. Fix a sequence $(Q_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of pairwise disjoint dense subsets in the real line.

Using Urysohn Lemma, construct inductively a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:X\to \mathbb R$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ the following conditions hold:

$\bullet$ $f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x)$ for every $x\in\bigcup_{k<n}D_k$;

$\bullet$ $f_n[D_n]\subseteq Q_n$;

$\bullet$ $\sup_{x\in X}|f_n-f_{n-1}|\le\frac1{2^n}$.

The last condition implies that the function sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\omega}$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$. The first two inductive conditions imply that $f[D_n]\subseteq Q_n$ for every $n\in\omega$.

This ensures that $f$ is nowhere locally constant. Indeed, for any nonempty open set $U\subseteq X$ choose any point $x\in U\cap D$ and find $n\in\omega$ such that $x\in D_n$. Since the set $D_n$ is closed and discrete in the crowded space $X$, the open set $U\setminus D_n$ is not empty and hence contains some point $y\in D_m$ with $m\ne n$. It follows from $f(x)\in f[D_n]\subseteq Q_n$, $f(y)\in f[D_m]\subseteq Q_m$ and $Q_n\cap Q_m=\emptyset$ that $f(x)\ne f(y)$, so $f{\restriction}_U$ is not constant and we are done. $\quad\square$

**Corollary.** *Every crowded metrizable space admits a locally nowhere constant continuous real-valued function.*

Theorems 1 and Corollary 2 suggest the following

**Problem.** *Is it true that every crowded submetrizable space (of density $\mathfrak c$) admit a nowhere locally constant continuous real-valued function?*

Answer (score 0):

By Gelfand duality, the category of abelian $C^*$-algebras is contravariantly equivalent to the category of all compact Hausdorff spaces, so it may be a good idea to try to characterize properties of topological spaces in terms of their dual abelian $C^*$-algebras and also in terms of the rings of continuous functions.

Let $C(X)$ denote the ring of all continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $C^*(X)$ denote the ring of bounded continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Observe that $C^{*}(X)\simeq C^{*}(\beta X).$ Let $C^{*}_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ denote the $C^{*}$-algebra of all bounded continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Observe that $C^{*}_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\simeq C^{*}_{\mathbb{C}}(\beta X)$ and recall that $C^{*}_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ is the dual $C^*$-algebra to the space $X$.

Observation: Let $X$ be a completely regular space. Then the following are equivalent.

1. Every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is constant on some non-empty open set.
2. For each $f\in C(X)$, there exists a $g\in C(X)\setminus\{0\}$ and a constant $\lambda$ with $fg=\lambda g$.
3. For each $f\in C^*(X)$, there exists a $g\in C^*(X)\setminus\{0\}$ and a constant $\lambda$ with $fg=\lambda g$.
4. For each Hermitian $f\in C^*_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$, there exists a $g\in C^*_{\mathbb{C}}(X)\setminus\{0\}$ and a constant $\lambda$ with $fg=\lambda g$.